# How can i add a dict as a another object to original nest in file

Tags: python, json

Let's assume this is database.json

```
{"data":[{
"uniqueid":[
        {"user_id":""},
        {"message_id":""},
        {"message":""},
        {"username":""}
    ]
},]}
```

Let's say i have this

```
data = {"uniqueid2":[
                  {"user_id":""},
                  {"message_id":""},
                  {"message":""},
                  {"username":""}]}
```

How can i add this to the existing database.json as a second Object in the original nest

Expected output in database.json:

```
{"data":[{
"uniqueid":[
        {"user_id":""},
        {"message_id":""},
        {"message":""},
        {"username":""}
    ]
},
     {"uniqueid2":[
                  {"user_id":""},
                  {"message_id":""},
                  {"message":""},
                  {"username":""}]}]}
```

I hope this isn't too complicated to understand, and i hope it's possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to `data` key

**Ex:**

```
database = {"data":[{
"uniqueid":[
        {"user_id":""},
        {"message_id":""},
        {"message":""},
        {"username":""}
    ]
},]}

data = {"uniqueid2":[
                  {"user_id":""},
                  {"message_id":""},
                  {"message":""},
                  {"username":""}]}

database['data'].append(data)
print(database)
```

**Output:**

```
{'data': [{'uniqueid': [{'user_id': ''},
                        {'message_id': ''},
                        {'message': ''},
                        {'username': ''}]},
          {'uniqueid2': [{'user_id': ''},
                         {'message_id': ''},
                         {'message': ''},
                         {'username': ''}]}]}
```

Comment: I don't understand how i haven't thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

Append the 2nd dictionary to the data key.

```
first_data = {"data":[{
    "uniqueid":[
        {"user_id":""},
        {"message_id":""},
        {"message":""},
        {"username":""}
    ]
    },]}

 first_data.append(data)
```